# In an example of "call options"

Tags: options

The following is an excerpt from *Introduction to the Mathematics of Finance* by Roman:

> As a more concrete example, suppose that IBM is selling for $\$100$ per share at
>   this moment. A $3$ month *call option* on IBM with *strike price* $\$102$ is a contract
>   between the buyer and the seller of the option that says that the buyer may (but is
>   not required to) purchase $\color{blue}{\bf 100}$ shares of IBM from the seller for $\$102$ per share at
>   any time during the next $3$ months.

In this example is the number $\color{blue}{100}$ in blue arbitrarily picked by the author? Is it relevant to the concept of "call option"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call options are usually standardized product: in the contract you can (but are not obliged to) buy a certain amount, which is specified. **The most common quantity is 100 shares** (see for example the description by J. Hull, *Options, Futures, and Other Derivatives*).

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's arbitrary, when you agree on the condition you define the how many shares and the Strike price if the contract is not standard